# Поток с циклом завершается только если внутри него выводится в консоль какая-то информация

Tags: java, многопоточность, swing

Java Swing.
Вот такая вот программка, суть которой такова: есть окно с кнопкой, за которой "прячется" несколько врагов (нажимаем - убиваем), как только убьем всех - выводим кол-во (нолик) в консоль. Чтобы не вывести кол-во врагов раньше времени - запускаем в разных потоках и ждем, пока завершится первый (выстрелы).

Поток продолжает работу, пока есть враги, именно для этого прописан цикл while, но вот незадача -- информация о оставшихся врагах отображается только если внутрь цикла поместить System.out.println(), в противном случае поток не завершается и ноль так и не выводится (будь в цикле хоть пустота, хоть увеличивающаяся с каждым шагом переменная). В чем же дело? Не захотелось бы захламлять консоль и вообще проводить лишние операции.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class MyFrame extends JFrame implements Runnable {
    public static int enemy=3;

    public MyFrame() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        setSize(500, 500);

        JButton jbtn = new JButton(String.valueOf(enemy));
        jbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                enemy--;
                jbtn.setText(String.valueOf(enemy));
            }
        });

        add(jbtn);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while(enemy>0) 
            System.out.println();   //без этого вывода поток не завершается
                                        //или мы просто не видим информацию?
    }

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyFrame());
                t1.start();

                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        try {
                            t1.join();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        System.out.println(MyFrame.enemy);
                    }
                }).start();

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно странная логика и лучше бы её реализовать как-то проще. Но в вашем случае проблема в том? что переменная изменяется в одно потоке, а проверяется в другом и чтобы во втором бралось актуальное значение надо использовать ключевое слово [volatile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html), т.е. что-то типа:

```
public static volatile int enemy=3;
```

Comment: Спасибо, понял.

...реализовать проще, например, вызывая новый класс (если enemy ==0), но в полной программе мне понадобится дважды вызывать этот класс по очереди, сохранять и сравнивать кол-во "выстрелов" в первый раз, и во второй, а создавать для этого поле, отвечающее за номер ходящего (втыкать условия дабы ничего раньше не вызвалось). я подумал - не очень идея.

Comment: @user193688 можно при уменьшении enemy надо тригерить некий эвент, на который подписаны разные другие обработчики. Посмотрите на паттерн наблюдатель - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)